# 4 buckets 4 balls question

Tags: probability

You randomly throw 4 balls into 4 buckets (each holds up to 2 balls). What is the probability that the number of non-empty buckets is 4. My friend keeps telling me that there are 18 final arrangements of the balls and only 1 arrangement that is [1,1,1,1] (4 non-empty buckets). So the probability is $$\frac{1}{18}$$

I am proposing that the probability is $$\frac{4 * 3 * 2 * 1}{4*4*4*4} = \frac{3}{32}$$

[image]

$$\mathbb{P}[0 non-empty] = 1 * \frac{3}{4} * \frac{2}{4} * \frac{1}{4} = \frac{4 * 3 * 2 * 1}{4*4*4*4} = \frac{3}{32}$$

Comment: What happens to a ball when you throw it "into" a bucket that is full?  How does it know where to go?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'd assume you'd rethrow the ball, then.

Comment: You cant throw a ball in a bucket that already has 2 balls, so you exclude it from further randomized throws. But that occurrence doesn't matter here.

Comment: @DanUznansk:  Absolutely not.  "each [bucket] hols up to 2 balls."

Comment: But jokes aside, the point of the question is that every ball must go into a bucket, and you are dispensing them randomly but without putting more than 2 in any bucket.

Comment: "the point of the question is that every ball must go into a bucket, and you are dispensing them randomly but without putting more than 2 in any bucket" is imprecise.  Is the "third" ball equally likely to go into a bucket with 0 balls and 1 balls?  Check that you realize that probability density function and radii, etc. are not the source of imprecision.

Answer (score 1):

I would tell him this:
1. The chances that the first ball hits a bucket are 100%
2. The chances that the second ball hits an empty bucket are 3/4
3. The chances that the third ball hits an empty bucket are 2/4
4. The chances that the fourth ball hits an empty bucket are 1/4
The chance of first and second and third and fourth event are 3/32.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is assuming a mechanism of "pouring" the (un-distinguishable) balls into the (distinguishable) baskets.
Something like that you put the baskets and the balls into a larger container, shake, turn bottom up etc. and finally open the container and 
register the occupancy histograms of the balls in the baskets.
In this case every possible histogram (actually $18+1 =19$ ) might be considered equi-probable.
Alternatively you may think to arrange the balls in a row, and "throw the baskets to the balls", i.e. the stars&bars procedure, where 
the distance between contiguous separators can be $0$, or $1$ or $2$.

Your mechanism is instead that of "throwing the balls to the baskets" which presumes that each ball  can land in either basket,
and which implicitly is labelling the balls according to the launching sequence order.
But with the limitation  of capacity of the baskets, while for the first and the second there are 4 choices, for the third and fourth there might be four or three depending on previous results.
 So your $4*4*4*4$ is not correct.
In fact, we have the launching tree depicted in this sketch

[image: 4Bins_4Balls_1]

Therefore the probability in your case is 
$$
{{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} \over {4 \cdot 3 \cdot 17}} = {2 \over {17}}
$$

Also refer to [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A019575)

The tree you are considering is instead that relevant to accounting for all the possible launches, even those
that result in 3 or 4 balls in the same basket and that you said that should be "cancelled" from the computation.

> So it's all a matter to define which is the **space of equi-probable events** that you, your friend (and me) shall agree on.

Comment: But it is. It wouldn't be 4 if we double filled one of them but we are not doing that. As soon as you double fill 1 its impossible to satisfy the 4 non-empty condition. So we are finding the probability to not double fill at all in 4 consecutive throws.

Comment: @MiteshKumar: in the $4^4$ space you can cancel (assign 0 prob.) to some events, but then the total "equiprobable" events are not $4^4$ anymore .. you have to find which is the amount of events to be cancelled and deduct them, from denominator and (in general, but not in this case) numerator as well. However you and your friend are considering two different schemas !

Comment: Hey I never said I was right. I just knew he was wrong. But i'm pretty sure my expression leads to the correct answer right? I drew out a tree structure with probabilities of all the events that could lead up to the desired ending.

Comment: @MiteshKumar: good, then just post the tree structure you obtained.

Comment: I added them to the post.

Answer (score 0):

There are 18 final arrangements of the balls, but that doesn't mean they all have to be equally $likely$.

This is easier to see when we allow four balls in every bucket and consider the configurations $[4,0,0,0]$ and $[1,1,1,1]$. There is only one way to get to the first configuration (landing your ball in the first bucket every throw), while there are $24$ ways to end up in the second situation.

The problem here is that the configurations as stated have an order-independence, and this is hidden by the fact that at first sight order *does* seem to matter. Sure, in $[2,1,1,0]$ it matters that the two goes first, but how we $got$ there (i.e. the order of the throws) is not relevant anymore.

Comment: Alexander Geldhof:  "each [bucket] holds up to $2$ balls."