# Probability of rolling a full house with 5 dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand the probability of rolling a full house with 5 dice. I can think of two methods. However, they disagree and I would like to understand why.

(1) For method 1, we compute the number of ways to roll a full house (with order mattering), and divide by the number of ordered rolls of 5 dice. This gives

$$P =  \frac{6\binom{5}3 5\binom{2}2}{6^5} \approx 0.0386. $$

This is also the accepted answer across multiple sources online.

(2) For method 2, we compute the number of possible full house rolls (with order NOT mattering), and divide by the number of rolls of 5 dice, again with order NOT mattering. The former is given by $2\binom{6}2$. The latter is a case of unordered sampling with replacement. The number of ways to obtain $k$ objects from $n$ in this case is

$$ \binom{n + k - 1}{k}. $$

Therefore, overall I would expect the probability of rolling a full house to be

$$ P = \frac{2\binom{6}2}{\binom{6 + 5 - 1}5} = 0.119. $$

Why does this disagree with method 1?

Comment: This is because in the second method  (essentially using "stars and bars") placements are not equiprobable, something that has been reiterated many times on this forum. See, eg  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804175/4-balls-are-placed-into-4-buckets-what-is-the-probability-that-exactly-1-bucket

Comment: They disagree because the second method says that getting a full house with three 2s and two 1s has the same probability as rolling all 1s (five of a kind). Real dice don't roll that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order matters.  Dice are distinguishable (for example, imagine they're five different colors so you can tell them apart - clearly making them out of colored material doesn't change the answer).  The first one is right.

For a simpler example: what's the probability of rolling a pair on two dice? It's clearly one-sixth. The analogue of your first method would give you $6/36$, where 6 is the number of ways of rolling a pair, namely $(1,1), (2,2), \ldots, (6,6)$, and 36 is the number of outcomes with two dice.  Here you have both, say $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$.

The analogue of your second method would give $6/21$, since there are ${6 + 2 - 1 \choose 2} = {7 \choose 2} = 21$ possible outcomes of two dice with order not mattering.

Comment: Thanks. As a followup, suppose I play poker with a simplified 6 card deck that has numbers 1,2,3 and 2 suits A, B.  What is the prob of getting a pair in a 2 card hand? Cards are dealt without replacement, so there are $\binom{6}2=15$ hands. There are also $\binom{3}1=3$ pairs. So overall the probability is $3/15=0.2$ to get a pair. Is this correct? If so, didn't this approach ignore ordering, which allowed me to use the binomial coefficient in the denominator? This feels very similar to method 2 outlined above, with the only difference being here sampling is w/o replacement

Comment: I see what you're saying. The difference is that in the cards case, every unordered hand, pair or non-pair, corresponds to two ordered hands.  But in the dice case, an unordered roll like $\{ 1, 1 \}$ corresponds to one ordered roll, while an unordered roll like $\{ 1, 2 \}$ corresponds to two ordered rolls $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$.  So the pairs look more common in the unordered setting than in the (correct) ordered setting.  Similarly for the full house - an unordered roll like $\{1, 1, 1, 2, 2\}$ corresponds to 10 different ordered rolls, which  is a relatively small number...

Comment: ...compared to most unordered rolls.   So full houses will appear more common in the unordered setting, your method (2), than they do in the ordered setting, which is your method (1).